# how to custom url wordpress show domain/category/post

Tags: wordpress

I want to show URL in post like "domain/category/post "

not include subcategory

```
e g

**domain.com/games/post**
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and then navigate to Permalinks and select **Custom Structure** and change the settings like below

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoMbc.png]

for more types refer this article https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/

Comment: thank, but I don't want it to show subcategories, what to do?

e g

domain.com/games/post

but now it show 

domain.com/game/a/post

Comment: change the Permalinks like above it will exclude sub-categories in the url

Comment: Yes i try change permalinks but it show https://domain.io/apps/utilities/post/

i would like show 

https://domain.io/apps/post

Comment: Check if any plugin is causing the problem. Because normally this method is perfect for removing the subcategory from the URL